# Put JSON data in yml file

Tags: json, ruby, yaml

I have a ruby file which returns a JSON data structure

```
    class BankDetails
      DETAILS = [
    {
      currencyCode: 'usd',
      currencyName: 'United States Dollar',
      iban: 'CH13 0070 0130 0089 9043 3',
      bankName: 'Zürcher Kantonalbank',
      bic: 'ZKBKCHZZ80A',
    },
    {
      currencyCode: 'chf',
      currencyName: 'Swiss Franc',
      iban: 'CH60 0070 0110 0067 2153 4',
      bankName: 'Zürcher Kantonalbank',
      bic: 'ZKBKCHZZ80A',
    },
    {
      currencyCode: 'eur',
      currencyName: 'Euro',
      iban: 'CH88 0070 0130 0089 9044 1',
      bankName: 'Zürcher Kantonalbank',
      bic: 'ZKBKCHZZ80A',
    },
    {
      currencyCode: 'zar',
      currencyName: 'South African Rand',
      iban: 'CH60 0070 0110 0067 2153 4',
      bankName: 'Zürcher Kantonalbank',
      bic: 'ZKBKCHZZ80A',
    },
    {
      currencyCode: 'nad',
      currencyName: 'Namibian Dollar',
      iban: 'CH60 0070 0110 0067 2153 4',
      bankName: 'Zürcher Kantonalbank',
      bic: 'ZKBKCHZZ80A',
    },

  ].freeze

  def self.fetch_bank_details
    DETAILS
  end
end
```

Now I want to put the same JSON into a new yml file and get the data in the same structure as I could get by calling the `BankDetails` class from the ruby file. What should be the exact structure of the yml file?

Comment: for a start, you can simply use JSON in a YAML file. JSON is a subset of YAML.

Comment: will this structure work?

```default:
  bank_details:
    - currency_code: usd
      currency_name: United States Dollar
      iban: CH13 0070 0130 0089 9043 3
      bank_name: Zürcher Kantonalbank
      bic: ZKBKCHZZ80A
    - currency_code: chf
      currency_name: Swiss Franc
      iban: CH60 0070 0110 0067 2153 4
      bank_name: Zürcher Kantonalbank
      bic: ZKBKCHZZ80A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be technically correct, what you have shown there is neither YAML nor JSON but a Ruby Array containing Hashes.

In this syntax, it is not valid JSON. By fixing the syntactic issues (quoting the keys, removing trailing commas), you could get a mostly equivalent JSON representation (as long as you instruct the parser to read the Hash keys as Symbols rather than Strings).

If you chose the correct subset of your code, it could be valid YAML, although parsing it that way won't get the exact same data structure as with this YAML, the hash keys would be parsed as Strings rather than Symbols again.

Thus, to get an equivalent YAML representation of your data structure, you should just use `YAML.dump` to emit a YAML document from your existing data structure:

```
require 'yaml'
puts YAML.dump(BankDetails::Details)
```

Comment: will this structure work?

```default:
  bank_details:
    - currency_code: usd
      currency_name: United States Dollar
      iban: CH13 0070 0130 0089 9043 3
      bank_name: Zürcher Kantonalbank
      bic: ZKBKCHZZ80A
    - currency_code: chf
      currency_name: Swiss Franc
      iban: CH60 0070 0110 0067 2153 4
      bank_name: Zürcher Kantonalbank
      bic: ZKBKCHZZ80A
```

Comment: That is impossible to say from the formatting in your comment. However, you can check it yourself it by parsing your file with `YAML.load_file('/path/to/file')` and comparing the parsed data structure to your original.

Comment: where should I write this piece of code? `YAML.load_file('/path/to/file')`